# What R function will return the number of characters contained in this variable?

Tags: r

In R I have a variable, h10.

```
> h10
[1] "<meta name=\"Distribution\" content=\"Global\" />"

> class(h10)
[1] "character"


> str(h10)
chr "<meta name=\"Distribution\" content=\"Global\" />"
```

I want to know the number of characters in h10, but length() returns 1 and not 45.

```
> length(h10)
[1] 1
```

What will return the number of characters? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `length` returns 1 is because `h10` is not a string, it's a string vector of length 1. It's important to know that in R, there are no "scalar" data types, only vectors. When you assign a string to a variable, as in `h10 <- '<meta name...'`, you're telling R to create a character vector of length 1 and assign this value to the first position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `nchar` (as commented) :

```
nchar(h10)
[1] 45
```

You can still use `length` after splitting you string to character's vector:

```
length(unlist(strsplit(h10,'')))
[1] 45
```

#### edit(thanks to @MatthewPlourde comment )  :

length returns 1 is because h10 is not a string, it's a string vector of length 1. It's important to know that in R, there are no "scalar" data types, only vectors. When you assign a string to a variable, as in `h10 <- '<meta name...>'`, you're telling R to create a character vector of length 1 and assign this value to the first position

Comment: And for fun `max(gregexpr("", h10)[[1]])`